# read email from outlook php from local pc

Tags: php, email, outlook

I have a strange requirement.

I need to read the outlook emails from a local pc using php .

I will get user credentials.

so is there any way to do this ?

it need to work well in all major browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with PHP and a browser.

Comment: @drew010 what about using some activex component ?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not aware of any that you wouldn't have to make the user install, but then it would only function in IE.

Comment: welcome, sorry it isn't doable.  best you could do is have them provide credentials and you can connect to their pop or smtp server and dl messages.

Comment: if you explained why you wanted this, an alternative could be found.

Comment: @drew010 No troubles :D [Actually i know this ,but i want to strengthen my knowledge ]

Comment: @Dagon No such good reason , Clients need this.They are thinking that outlook is the emperor of email/email protocols.

Comment: imap, let outlook get the mail but leave it on server and then its still evaluable through a php script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to try to get this from a LOCAL mail file on a 'single' pc, I would rather attack this from a `POP3/IMAP` route, it would THEN be a PHP based mail client, or whatever you need it for (fetching mail, filtering, checking, triggering an event, etc;).

But what you describe is just not feasible for anything, I can't see a client paying to have simple client mail accessed via PHP.

**Here are some PHP / Email reading references:**

- http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/reading-emails-with-php/
- http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap
- http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/15/6/3

Comment: Thanks for the info ,i  described the scenario with client,hope they will revert back.Thank you.

Comment: sooo... you're going to wait for your client to decide if this is a good answer for StackOverflow? ;)

Comment: Pardon me bro , i cannot accept your answer.Because the answer is irrelevant to the exact question.But it is useful :)

Comment: Good answer for handling IMAP, but I do have a similar use case in which people want to be able to easily import emails from their inbox into our system, and it's actually easier for a lot of people to quickly drag and drop a bunch of emails onto their Desktop / into a folder, and then drag those over the browser window that has our system open (we support drag and drop) than it is for them to connect to their inbox via our system, etc. Point being, we have the IMAP thing going, and it's nice, but a way to read the local .msg files from Outlook, etc. would be nice.